# How do I add an attachment to a table with a migration? (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activestorage

I have a posts table and I want to add a video attachment (I'm using ActiveStorage).

I tried to create the following migration:

```
class AddVideoToPosts < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  def change
    add_column :posts, :video, :attachment
  end
end
```

But when I run `rails db:migrate` I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  type "attachment" does not exist
```

Forgive me if this is a simple fix. I'm new to Rails. Thank you!

Comment: I suggest reading https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#setup

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need any migrations for some specific model attachments

Just add such line to model

```rb
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  has_one_attached :video
end
```

or

```rb
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  has_many_attached :videos
end
```

That's all

Of course it will work only if you set up Active Storage and have Active Storage tables

If you haven't such tables — add them with

```
bin/rails active_storage:install
bin/rails db:migrate
```

This sets up configuration, and creates the three tables Active Storage uses:

- `active_storage_blobs` stores data about uploaded files, such as filename and content type
- `active_storage_attachments`, a polymorphic join table that connects your models to blobs. If your model's class name changes, you will need to run a migration on this table to update the underlying record_type to your model's new class name
- `active_storage_variant_records`, if variant tracking is enabled, stores records for each variant that has been generated

Please see details in [official guide](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html)